# AES Encryption in android and decryption in php and vice versa

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio, aes

I am trying to learn AES by testing my code against https://aesencryption.net. I previously had an error in `Base64.encodeBase64String` and also `Base64.decodeBase64 // encode/decode Base64`. So I manipulated Base64 somehow to resolve the error. Now in my app the text is encrypted and decrypted properly, I think. But when I try to encrypt or decrypt the same text server-side (at aesencryption.net), the site is not able to decrypt my encrypted string. Please help.

Following is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String TAG = "SymmetricAlgorithmAES";
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey ;
    private static byte[] key ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Original text
        // {"type":"Success","httpCode":"200","code":"200","message":{"pin":"11111"},"extra":""}
        String theTestText = "hi";
        TextView tvorig = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvorig);
        tvorig.setText("\n[ORIGINAL]:\n" + theTestText + "\n");
        final String strPssword = "android";
        setKey(strPssword);

        // Encode the original data with AES
        byte[] encodedBytes = null;
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey);
            encodedBytes = c.doFinal(theTestText.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "AES encryption error");
        }

        TextView tvencoded = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvencoded);
        tvencoded.setText("[ENCODED]:\n" +
                Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT) + "\n");

        Log.d(TAG, Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));


        // Decode the encoded data with AES
        byte[] decodedBytes = null;
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            decodedBytes = c.doFinal(encodedBytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "AES decryption error");
        }
        TextView tvdecoded = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdecoded);
        tvdecoded.setText("[DECODED]:\n" + new String(decodedBytes) + "\n");
    }



    public static void setKey(String myKey){
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(key.length);
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
            System.out.println(key.length);
            System.out.println(new String(key,"UTF-8"));
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");


        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AES has different encryption modes, including "salted" ones. You have to know what mode the website is using before you clone it in your application.

Comment: I am trying to decrypt the same code from https://aesencryption.net/#Java-aes-encryption-example .There also i am unable to decrypt or encrypt.

Comment: AES is a block cipher that can have [different modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). So if your website (which, I'm assuming, is in PHP) uses one mode of operation while your application is using another, you will be getting different results. In addition to that, AES results depend on what [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) you use. Make sure it's the same on both ends.

Comment: @Pyromonk Thanks for your time.This case was actually in my mind.But the thing is, the aes website itself has given the code in java and an online way to check the same . In my code also , i have little things manipulated which i am not sure will effect in the website as i have not changed the modes. So in the app i can easily encrypt or decrypt the strings.But when i am taking that encrypted string and run in aes website,i am unable to decryppt that.

Comment: Make sure the following holds true and run another test: 1) The string you encrypt only contains ANSI characters (A-Z, a-z, _, -, 0-9, etc.); 2) "Key of encryption" is blank in both cases; 3) the block size is 256 bit in both cases.

Comment: Where is the PHP code?

Comment: @Puneet Please refer aesencryption.net  same php code is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like this which actually works ;)

```
public class AESCrypter {
    private final Cipher cipher;
    private final SecretKeySpec key;
    private AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;


    public AESCrypter(String password) throws Exception
    {
        // hash password with SHA-256 and crop the output to 128-bit for key
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        spec = getIV();
    }

    public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV()
    {
        byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
        ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        return ivParameterSpec;
    }

    public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception
    {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String encryptedText = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");

        return encryptedText;
    }

    public String decrypt(String cryptedText) throws Exception
    {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(cryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        String decryptedText = new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");

        return decryptedText;
    }
}
```

Call this class like this :

```
 try {
            AESCrypter _crypt = new AESCrypter("password");
            String output = "";
            String plainText = "top secret message";
            output = _crypt.encrypt(plainText); //encrypt
            System.out.println("encrypted text=" + output);
            output = _crypt.decrypt(output); //decrypt
            System.out.println("decrypted text=" + output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And for iPhone (Code is here) : `https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC`

Hope this code works for you too :)

Comment: **Security warning** The usage of a static IV makes your encryption **vulnerable and/or unsecure**, please use a random generated IV instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code uses CBC mode by default while your Java code does not specify the same, and leaves it to the underlying implementation. If I recall correctly its probably `ECB/PKCS5Padding`. Your PHP implementation is using 'CBC' with no padding (mcrypt doesn't support padding by default but you can do so manually).

Its very important be be very specific about mode, padding, and charset when working with different platforms else you will run into different defaults.

Try initializing your cipher as follows: `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");`

Comment: Thanks for your time. I manipulate the code and now it works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    fun encrypt(encrypted: String): String? {
        try {
            val secretKey = "secretKey" //The secret key, 32 bytes string.
            val ivKey = "ivKey" // The initialization vector, 16 bytes string.
            val iv = IvParameterSpec(hashIV.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
            val skySpec = SecretKeySpec(hashKey.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), "AES-256-CBC")
            val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skySpec, iv)
            val original: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(encrypted.toByteArray())
            return Base64.encode(
                Base64.encodeToString(original, Base64.NO_WRAP).toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")),
                Base64.NO_WRAP
            ).decodeToString()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }

    fun decrypt(encrypted: String?): String? {
        try {
            val secretKey = "secretKey" //The secret key, 32 bytes string.
            val ivKey = "ivKey" // The initialization vector, 16 bytes string.
            val iv = IvParameterSpec(hashIV.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
            val skySpec = SecretKeySpec(hashKey.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), algorithm)
            val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation)
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skySpec, iv)
            val original: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(
                Base64.decode(
                    Base64.decode(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP
                )
            )
            return original.decodeToString()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
```

[openssl_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)

Comment: **Security warning** The usage of a static IV makes your encryption **vulnerable and/or unsecure**, please use a random generated IV instead. Thanks.